# How to create a datetime object with tzinfo set as 'UTC'?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of datetimes objects :

```
time_range = [datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
              datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
              datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
              datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
              ... ]
```

And I have an other datetime object :

```
time = datetime(2019, 7, 7)
```

I have to test if `time` is in `time_range`.
But each time I test :

```
time in time_range
```

I get the output `False`, because I don't have the `tzinfo`.

**Here's what I've tried :**

I tried to add the tzinfo :

```
time = datetime(2019, 7, 7, tzinfo=tzuct())
```

but I can't find where the `tzutc()` function is.

I also tried tu use pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(str(time) + '+00:00')
```

I get the `UTC` :

```
Timestamp('2019-07-05 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

But this is not a `datetime.datetime` object...

Do you have an idea how I could do ?

(Note : i'm compelled to use the form `time in time_range`, because of the rest of my program)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `datetime` constructor, `tzinfo` parameter expects a type of [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone). It's not the clearest documentation. Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime(2019, 7, 7, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone

>>> time = datetime(2019, 7, 7, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

>>> print(time)
2019-07-07 00:00:00+00:00

>>> print(time.tzinfo)
UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found an other solution, using pandas :

```
utc_time = pd.to_datetime(str(time) + '+00:00').to_pydatetime()
```

returns a `datetime.datetime` object :

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

However, to avoid importing pandas library, here's the solution I used :

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
new_time = time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
new_time in time_range.

>>> True
```